# bootstrap-datetimepicker: Fix the minutes to a certain value

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Is there a way to fix the minutes of a datetimepicker to a certain value? For the hours there is the enableHours() and disableHours() function, but the same does not seem to exist for minutes?
cheers
carl

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding the following function

```
.on('dp.show', function () {
    $('a.btn[data-action="incrementMinutes"], a.btn[data-action="decrementMinutes"]').removeAttr('data-action').attr('disabled', true);
    $('span.timepicker-minute[data-action="showMinutes"]').removeAttr('data-action').attr('disabled', true).text('17');
});
```

where now the minutes are fixed to 17... I think the datetimepicker people should add a function like that